# net core app fails to access azure key vault

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I am trying to use Azure key vault to store some secrets.  Following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/vs-secure-secret-appsettings

works while debugging, but when I publish the app to Azure, it fails by returning null for my key.

I then tried this tutorial: https://medium.com/@patoncrispy/securing-settings-in-dot-net-core-apps-using-azure-key-vault-d4ec82de00b8

this also works during debugging, but when I publish to Azure, it also fails by returning null for my key.

any help in where I should look on how to resolve this would be great.  Why would I get null in production, but not debugging when the same credentials are supplied?

Comment: Have you enabled Managed Service Identity in Azure?

Comment: @juunas I did not, but I have now. Do I have to specify the environmental variable in launchsettings.json or appsettings in azure?

Comment: Appsettings become env vars. But what are you adding to env vars?

Comment: That first link uses en vars for the vault url. I hard-coded that and now it fails with no stack trace output in the streaming log of Azure. So now I have a completely different error. The vault doesn't show a request either

Comment: It should be able to get the app setting if you specify it with the name `KEYVAULT_ENDPOINT`

Comment: ok, for some reason the streaming log took a 2 minutes to display the stack trace and its related to my DI service.  So yeah...all it took was flipping the identity of the app lol.  Thank you so much!  Add as an answer for credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the app to be able to access the Key Vault in Azure using the AppAuthentication library, it should have Managed Service Identity enabled.

In addition the automatically created service principal needs to be given access to the secrets in Key Vault.

Specifying the KeyVault endpoint URL in Azure can be done using an app setting with the key `KEYVAULT_ENDPOINT` in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a new secret client using the default credential from Azure.Identity using environment variables previously set,
// including AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, and AZURE_TENANT_ID.
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Create a new secret using the secret client.
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.SetSecret("secret-name", "secret-value");

// Retrieve a secret using the secret client.
secret = client.GetSecret("secret-name");
```